# Object extending Array with Functional Inheritance

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototypal-inheritance

Using [functional inheritance](http://julien.richard-foy.fr/blog/2011/10/30/functional-inheritance-vs-prototypal-inheritance/) we can extend objects by passing them as the context of a function call assigning to `this`.

This doesn't seem to work as I'd expect for the `Array` constructor.

```
var ctx = {
    foo: "foo"
};

Array.call(ctx);
```

`ctx` -> `Object(foo: "foo")`

Conversely this does work with other constructor looking functions.

```
var fakeArrayConstructor = function () {
    this.length = 5;
}

fakeArrayConstructor.call(ctx);
```

`ctx` -> `Object {foo: "foo", length: 5}`

Does the `Array` constructor not assign some of its properties using `this` or is there something else going on? I know that a lot of the functionality associated with arrays is stored on `Array.prototype` however that's not my focus for this exercise.

Comment: Array takes an argument as input. So `Array.call(null, ctx)` works

Comment: you seem to confuse the two. functional inheritance, as presented in the article you linked, does *not* use `Array.call`.

Comment: You will want to read http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/

Comment: Sorry but aren't built ins basically bindings to C++ that can do any amount of anything under the hood and don't have to follow any javascript rules, except the explicitly defined ones in the standards..?

Comment: @Winchestro: Everything in JavaScript is just an exposed binding to some lower-level stuff that conforms to the standard rules. That's basically how every language works…

Comment: Thanks for your answers and comments. If this is the case that the Array function is just different, just because it is, then it leads to asking why the examples of its use (MDN for example) use the `new` keyword at all. To me, by explicitly controlling the context (`this`) using `new`, there's the implication that it's (the context) important somehow. Perhaps it is but not for assignment reasons? (You can simply call `Array` as a non-constructor function after all).

Comment: @JamieDixon: Being explicit is better than implicit - so when invoking a constructor, you should always use `new`, regardless whether it does or does not need it. That being said, it's convention in JS to always use array literals instead of the constructor.

Comment: @Bergi yeah sorry you're right, I should have be more precise. Some built ins are just not extendable, no matter what you do. The best we can do is augment some behavior in JS, often with huge performance costs, but as they can do a lot more a lot faster in C++ it's usually better not to it and just take JS as it is and make the best out of it  ^^

Answer (score 1):

Functional Inheritance in the linked article is not using `call`.

Please correct me if I am wrong. The `Array` function happens to have a peculiar implementation, but that is orthogonal to this question. In order to make functional inheritance work, constructor functions need to be written to support it.

Your `Array.call` approach is sometimes used to simulate inheritance, but this approach requires methods to be assigned to the instance from directly inside the constructor function, which is probably the exception rather than the rule in most cases.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Douglas Crockford coined the term "functional inheritance" in his book JavaScript: The Good Parts when discussing inheritance patterns. It's hard to tell from text but am I right to assume you disagree with this in some way? (That's usually what people mean when they refer to something as "so-called"). I think you're right about the internals not working as I'd expect. My comment above about the `new` keyword mostly covers that. The behavior seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: I have updated my answer with "improved" understanding.

Comment: @JamieDixon No, I have no real opinion on it having only a cursory knowledge of the approach. I used the quotes to indicate that as an idiom, as far as I know, it is not yet mainstream.

Comment: In the article linked to the author doesn't use the `call` function. In Eric Elliot's article on Three Different Kinds of prototypal OO, he does use this approach: http://ericleads.com/2013/02/fluent-javascript-three-different-kinds-of-prototypal-oo/ If you're not assigning to `this` within your constructor, are there other reasons to create objects using `new`?

Comment: AFAIC remember, `new` will do three things for you (over and above creating a plain object): 1 - set the receiver (i.e. `this`), 2 - it will place the `.prototype` of the constructor function on the prototype chain of the resulting instance, 3 - return the resulting object by default. If you need this functionality, then `new` is useful. If you don't need this functionality, then `new` is not useful :)

Comment: As to opinions, there are some people in the JS community who do not like `new` because it "looks like Java". I dislike Java as much as the next man, but all the implementations I have seen where they avoid it use object literals to instantiate objects, which is equivalent to writing `new Object`, so personally I have some scepticism.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I appreciate your time to chat over these things. I think the only reason for the `new` keyword in this Array context is just for the prototype functions. I supposed I'd have to find one of the implementers of JS to really find out why it does what it does. As for reasons not to use constructor functions I think Eric explains it very well. Looking like Java is the least of the issues. http://ericleads.com/2012/09/stop-using-constructor-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: No problem! Yes, interesting talk.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, functional inheritance allows you to avoid reference to the `this` keyword all together. The example you linked clearly shows that.

The `Array` global object is implementation defined but we can assume that all properties are assigned to `__proto__` and not `this`.